# How to pass multiple parameters from salesforce to tableau using Tableau viz lightning web component?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, tableau

Can we pass multiple parameters from salesforce to tableau using Tableau viz lightning component ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the Product Manager for embedding Tableau inside Salesforce. We don't have a way to pass multiple parameters, but it is on our roadmap. You can open a feature request on GitHub: https://github.com/tableau/tableau-viz-lwc/issues to track it.